# How to use the adjacent sibling combinator?

Tags: css

We're trying to control vertical spacing on content and have everything working great except when content follows a div - consider the following:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We'd like to remove top margin from all ul's that immediately follow a div so have been trying:

```
div + ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Is this the proper use for this selector?

We just can't seem to get it working - any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: ***immediately follow a div*** this together with the HTML code you posted show me that you may want to mean **the first direct child**, so the rule should be `div > ul:first-child`

Comment: Adjacent selector would be for something like `<div></div> <ul>`

Comment: I'll add that (I believe) it's uncommon to declare margin-top on ul elements, usually you pad the container.

Comment: @King King - bang on, god knows what I was thinking!

Answer (score 2):

It has the word "adjacent" in it, this means "next to": your `ul` is not "next to" your `div` (on the same hierarchical level) but **inside** it.

What you want is a direct (not recursive) child selector, `>` so:

```
div > ul { ... }
```

And if it only happens to the first child of that `div`:

```
div > ul:first-child { ... }
```